# how to retrieve a column value by passing another column value

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa, hql

I have a table client having a column cid.

The entity class is

```
public class client{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "version")
    private Integer version;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    private Client cid;

....
}
```

In my session I have kept the client id and retrieving by the following way

```
String clientId = request.getSession().getAttribute("clientId").toString();
```

This is my controller code

```
 List l=serviceClientServiceImpl.getSavedParents(clientId);
    uiModel.addAttribute("savedParents",l);
```

This is my getSavedParents code

```
public List getSavedParents(String cid)
{
    List l=serviceClientDaoImpl.getSavedParents(cid);
    return l;
}
```

and this is my query code

```
public List getSavedParents(String cid)
{
    String queryString="select distinct pid from ClientParentQuestion where cid="+cid;
    Query query=entityManagerUtil.getQuery(queryString);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

when I try to receive in my jsp using `${savedParents}` then I get nothing.

I do not understand where do I make mistake.

Can any body solve my problem?

Comment: Where is the code for `ClientParentQuestion`?

Comment: Can you update your question for every one to see?

Comment: Ok, that's good to hear!

Comment: @geoand I have another problem,Can you help me please?If yes then please come to my [chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44929/java-and-jquery-beginners) as we can not talk off the topics here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

So client has a self-reference to itself.

I'd refactor the dao method to:

```
public List getSavedParents(String cid) {
    return getEntityManager()
            .createQuery("select distinct cpq.pid from ClientParentQuestion cpq where cpq.cid.id = :cid")
            .setParameter("cid, Long.valueOf(cid))
            .getResultList();
}
```

Also use an alias for the entity when you want to specify what properties you'd like to return or match.

It's much more readable and it follows the JPQL/HQL projection idioms.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,I did your way but I do not get any value

Comment: Check my updated response, cid was Client object not a String. Assuming it's id is the one passed as a String argument that's how the query should look like. Also I can't see what's pid from Client. Is it a number?

Comment: Also you were sending a String argument (cid) and you wanted to match the Client.cid.id, meaning the client's parent id. Check my updated code.

Comment: I have another problem not related to this question.can you come to my [chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44929/java-and-jquery-beginners) please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54720/discussion-between-vlad-mihalcea-and-jquerylearner).